# Second order ODE with initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following second order differential equation

$$ \frac{d^2\theta \:}{dt^2\:}\:=-\frac{g\theta \:\:}{L} $$ with initial conditions $$θ(0) = θ_0 , v(0) = v_0  $$

I know that I can rewrite the equation as

$$ \frac{d^2\theta \:}{dt^2\:}\:+\frac{g\theta \:\:}{L} = 0 $$

, find characteristic polynomial and solve the equation. I am just confused on how to solve this problem because of all the constants. 
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: What I am confused about is how should the characteristic equation look like?

Comment: This is what I got, which is probably wrong, but here it goes   $$λ = +- sqrt(g/L) i $$. This is the "normal"  way if we don't have any first derivative. I don't get the same answer when using a computer, symolab.com. What it gives me is $$ L = -(g/λ^2)$$. This exercise may not be so hard, but right now it feels impossible. Btw, this is a simple pendulum exercise for small angles

Comment: I know, I am stressed! I have tried it tho, but this time it solves for g

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d^2\theta \:}{dt^2\:}\:+\frac{g\theta \:\:}{L} = 0$$
Characteristic polynomial is
$$r^2+\frac g L=0 \implies r=\pm i \sqrt {\frac gl}$$
Then the solution is
$$\theta(t)=c_1\cos(\sqrt {\frac gl}t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\frac gl}t)$$
Apply initial conditions now

$$θ(0) = θ_0 ,\implies \theta(0)=c_1   \implies c_1=\theta_0$$
$$\theta(t)=\theta_0\cos(\sqrt{\frac gl}t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\frac gl}t)$$
Differentiate
$$\theta(t)'=\sqrt{\frac gl} \left(-\theta_0\sin(\sqrt{\frac gl}t)+c_2\cos(\sqrt{\frac gl}t) \right )$$
Apply the second inditial condition to find $c_2$
$$\theta(0)'=\sqrt{\frac gl} c_2 \implies c_2=v_0\sqrt{\frac lg}$$
Finally
$$\theta(t)=\theta_0\cos \left(\sqrt{\frac gl}t \right)+v_0\sqrt{\frac lg}\sin \left (\sqrt{\frac gl}t \right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much sir/ma'am! It helped a lot

Comment: @RAA you're welcome...